# How to do something different for every part of a code?

Tags: php

I have codes like an MD5 hash, and I want to use them like a code for a sequence of instructions:

```
<?php

$code = "jeu7395j6jf102m9ns7ij787ggh545h1";

// for every character from the first to
// the last, do something different depending
// on what the character is. if 5 do this,
// if p do that, etc.
```

Is there a simple way of doing this in PHP without using a library?

I'm new to this, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is kinda very clear what he is asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is all over the internet, but I guess that's difficult to find if you don't quite know the language/terminology and concepts of programming yet. Try not to get discouraged by the downvoters. :)

You can do this with a for loop and a switch:

```
<?php

$code = "jeu7395j6jf102m9ns7ij787ggh545h1";
$code_length = strlen($code);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $code_length); $i++) {
    switch ($code[$i-1]) {
        case 'a':
            // do this
            break;
        case 'b':
            // do that
            break;
        // case 'c' and so on for every matched character
    }
}
```

We assign the strlen() to $code_length for performance optimization, that way we're not executing strlen() with every iteration of the for loop.

Using `if` statements might be fewer lines than a `switch` in your case, but switches are a more versatile control structure in situations like this, and they're also more explicit.

See also [for loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), [switches](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
function pj(){
 //do a
}

function p7(){
 //do b
}

function pe(){
 //do c
}

...
...
function p1(){
  //do Nn
}

foreach(explode('',$code) as $fname){
   $function ='p' . $fname;
   $function();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just a simple for loop:

```
$str = "String to loop through";
$strlen = strlen( $str );

for ($i = 0; $i <= $strlen; $i++) {
    $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
    if ($char == 't')
      echo 'Do t stuff!';
}
```

You would want to create a rule for each character obviously, a switch statement makes sense, but I've used an if statement for the letter `t` as an example.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka Yup, exactly what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it:

```
  $code = "jeu7395j6jf102m9ns7ij787ggh545h1";


  for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($code); $i < $j; $i++) {
       switch ($code[$i]){
            case "a":
            //do something when it's 'a'
            break;

            case "b":
            //do something when it's 'b'
            break;  

            case "1":
            //do something when it's '1'
            break;  

       }
  }
```